# How do I make excel write to the top of the page again?

Tags: python, excel, csv

I'm trying to write to to a csv document at the top after a for loop.
Eg:

Cell1 Cell2 Cell3

1

2

3

4

---

^ 
I AM HERE
How would I then write underneath Cell2?

I haven't been able to try anything since I am stumped at this point.

```py
            with open("{} results.csv".format(file), "w+") as exportfile:
                writer = csv.writer(exportfile, delimiter=',')
                writer.writerow(['Times', '', 'Photographer ID', '', 'Calculations Completed', '', 'Start time of set', '', 'End time of set'])
                for i in finaltimes:
                    writer.writerow([i])
                writer.writerow('TEST')
```

With 'TEST' it displays as:

Cell1 Cell2 Cell3

1

2

3

4

T  E  S  T

---

Not at the start of Cell2

Comment: Ideally with a CSV you would be writing each full row sequentially - CSV is not [trivially] a "random access"-type format.  Something like `writer.writerow([i, 'TEST'])` would be more appropriate here.

Comment: This doesn't work for what I need it to do. This adds 'TEST' down the side of each timestamp when I only need it displayed once.

Answer (score 0):

you can put the data into a pandas dataframe then write it to CSV and it will include the column names and write all the data the way you want

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['Times', 'Photographer ID','Calculations Completed', 'Start time of set','End time of set'])

i=0
for col in df.columns:
    df[col]=your_data_array[:,i]
    i+=1

df.to_csv('results.csv',index=False)
```

modify as necessary for your purpose, but basic algorithm is to put the data into a dataframe then use the df.to_csv function

Comment: I really love the idea except I'm going for a program that only uses pythons built in libraries. Sorry I didn't mention this sooner !